# Why can't the compiler deduce the return type if argument type depends on a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I am getting a template deduction error when trying to choose a function of an overload set (`foo`) within a template based on another template parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(int a){
    std::cout << "int";
}

void foo(double a) {
    std::cout << "double";
}

template <typename T, typename R>
void print(const T& data, R(*fun)(typename T::type) ) {
    fun(data.value);   
}

struct IntData{
    using type = int;
    type value;
};

int main()
{
  IntData x{1};
  print(x, foo);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
In function 'int main()':
27:15: error: no matching function for call to 'print(IntData&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
27:15: note: candidate is:
15:6: note: template<class T, class R> void print(const T&, R (*)(typename T::type))
15:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
27:15: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'R'
```

As template deduction should proceed from left to right, my assumption was that once the type of `T` is deduced, the type of `R` should also be deducable. Actually, I can get rid of the error when calling print like

```
print<IntData>(x, foo);
```

which seems to show that `R` can actually be deduced once `T` is known. So why doesn't it work if both parameter should be deduced?

Thank you!

Comment: Chicken, meet egg! What if there's another `print` template somewhere?

Comment: Deduction doesn't proceed left to right -- deduction is performed independently for each parameter and then the results collated , with an error if any two different parameters succeeded but produced conflicting deductions. You should get the exact same error if you remove the `const T&` parameter

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings that would not be relevant

Comment: @M.M I don't see why not? The potential for there to be more than one function template to pick from did at least in part drive the way the deduction rules were constructed, surely?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings template deduction is based on what's visible (in the declaration and instantiation contexts), in general extra specializations or overloads that aren't visible cause the program to be ill-formed NDR

Comment: @M.M I'm not talking about things that aren't visible

Comment: @M.M thanks for your fast answer. I thought they were talking about the order here:hat i: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368022/why-does-the-order-of-template-argument-substitution-matter ?

Comment: @Timo that question talks about the order of substitution of *template parameters*. The examples on that page only have one function parameter ; but each function parameter is processed independently (and a part of that processing is that tentative deductions are substituted left to right in the template parameter list)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is because you have `R` as the return type for your function pointer argument.

Note this quote [from a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature#:~:text=For%20functions%20that%20are%20specializations,not%20part%20of%20the%20signature.)

> So, when we ask about the signature of a function, we have to give two answers:
>
> For functions that **are specializations of function templates**, the
>   signature **includes the return type**.
>
> For functions that **are not specializations**, the **return type is not part of the signature**.

Since `foo` is simply an overloaded function and `void` is not part of the `foo` function signature, `R` will **not** assist the compiler in deducing correct function overload. Therefore, the use of `foo` as a function pointer is ambiguous within the scope of main. The compiler usually resolves the overload by matching the types of the provided arguments, for which there are none when the function pointer is by itself.

I believe this is the most robust solution, to include an intermediary function to resolve the previously ambiguous function pointer. I included some other types in addition to int to demonstrate the flexibility of using auto with the strategies mentioned below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(int a){
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}

void foo(double a) {
    std::cout << "double" << std::endl;
}

bool foo(char a) {
    std::cout << "char" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename R>
R print(const T& data, R(*fun)(typename T::type) ) {
    return fun(data.value);   
}

struct IntData{
    using type = int;
    type value;
};
struct DoubleData{
    using type = double;
    type value;
};
struct CharData{
    using type = char;
    type value;
};
template <typename T>
auto print2(const T& data)
{
  auto(*fooResolved)(typename T::type) = foo;
  return print(data,fooResolved);
}

int main()
{
  IntData x{1};
  print2(x);

  DoubleData y{1.0};
  print2(y);

  CharData z{'a'};
  bool result = false;
  std::cout << "bool before: " << result << std::endl;
  result = print2(z);
  std::cout << "bool after : " << result << std::endl;
}
```

Here are a few more potential solutions to help illustrate the problem:

(note the change is removing R as the second template argument)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(int a){
    std::cout << "int";
}

void foo(double a) {
    std::cout << "double";
}

template <typename T>
void print(const T& data, void(*fun)(typename T::type) ) {
    fun(data.value);   
}

struct IntData{
    using type = int;
    type value;
};

int main()
{
  IntData x{1};
  print(x, foo);
}
```

As well as this (passing the value directly, which allows for multiple return types)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(int a){
    std::cout << "int";
}

void foo(double a) {
    std::cout << "double";
}

template <typename T, typename R>
void print(const T& data, R (*fun)(T) ) {
    fun(data);   
}

struct IntData{
    using type = int;
    type value;
};

int main()
{
  IntData x{1};
  print(x.value, foo);
}
```

And to further illustrate the original issue (see the return type is now deduced)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(int a){
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}

bool foo(double a) {
    std::cout << "double" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

template <typename T, typename R>
R print(const T& data, R (*fun)(T) ) {
    return fun(data);   
}

struct IntData{
    using type = int;
    type value;
};
struct DoubleData{
    using type = double;
    type value;
};

int main()
{

  IntData x{1};
  print(x.value, foo);

  //foo(int) does not return a value
  //bool test = print(x.value, foo); // Does not compile

  DoubleData y{1.0};

  bool result = false;
  result = print(y.value, foo);
  std::cout << result << std::endl;

}
```

And while we're at it, you could also resolve them given the original code by explicitly specifying which foo you want

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(int a){
    std::cout << "int";
}

void foo(double a) {
    std::cout << "double";
}

template <typename T, typename R>
void print(const T& data, R(*fun)(typename T::type) ) {
    fun(data.value);   
}

struct IntData{
    using type = int;
    type value;
};

int main()
{
  IntData x{1};
  void(*fooResolved)(int) = foo;
  print(x, fooResolved);
}
```